# Powershell to read CSV header with space

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a powershell script to parse a CSV file and add a new value to specific header. For Example Input file is a header and i want to replace the value under it. I have added the logic and it works for normal hearder but as this header has a space i am not able to manage it. Can you please help me how can i manage the space

## Convert into CSV

```
Import-CSV $CSV_File | ForEach-Object {
{$_.Input file} = "$machine_path\file"
{$_.Output file} ="$machine_path\Output"
$_ |  Export-Csv $machine_path\new.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to dereference a property with spaces in the name, use quotation marks:

```
Import-CSV $CSV_File | ForEach-Object {
  $_.'Input file' = "$machine_path\file"
  $_.'Output file' = "$machine_path\Output"
  $_ 
}| Export-Csv $machine_path\new.csv -NoTypeInformation
```